# Will a flash grenade blind a hero?

Tags: star-wars-battlefront-2015

The [flash grenade](http://battlefront.wikia.com/wiki/Flash_Grenade) is not a particular effective [Star Card](http://battlefront.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Card), it doesn't do any damage and if your not careful you have a decent chance of blinding yourself with it.
[image: Flash grenade]
I was wondering, however, if it can be used to blind enemy heroes?

This would make it, a little more useful.  Or are heroes less sensitive or immune to the blinding effect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[A-MinorBish](https://www.reddit.com/user/A-MinorBish) on the [Battlefront subreddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/StarWarsBattlefront/comments/46il27/will_a_flash_grenade_blind_a_hero/d05goeg) says:

> Yes they do. The flash grenade is a vital tool I use to annoy/wreck
>   heroes. It also blinds yourself as well if you aren't careful though.